# How to position expand icon on the right side of the accordion while keeping the text in the center?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am learning Material UI and i want that my icons to expand stays on the right side of my accordion and not moves with the text to the center. I tried a couple of options but they did not lead to the desired outcome.

My question is how to postion the icon on the right side of the accordion?

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-currying-dt3bv?file=/src/index.js)

```
const Accordion = withStyles({
  root: {
    border: 'none',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    '&:not(:last-child)': {
      borderBottom: 0,
    },
    '&:before': {
      display: 'none',
    },
    '&$expanded': {
      margin: 'auto',
    },
  },
  expanded: {},
})(MuiAccordion);

const AccordionSummary = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)',
   // borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)',
    marginBottom: -1,
    minHeight: 56,
    '&$expanded': {
      minHeight: 56,
    },
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    '&$expanded': {
    flexGrow: 0,
      margin: '12px 0',
    },
  },
  expanded: {},
  expandIcon:{
    order: 0,
  },
})(MuiAccordionSummary);

const AccordionDetails = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}))(MuiAccordionDetails);



export default function CustomizedAccordions() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState('panel1');

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  return (

    <div>
      <Accordion square expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1') }>
        <AccordionSummary 
           aria-controls="panel1d-content" 
           expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
           id="panel1d-header">
          <Typography>Collapsible Group Item #1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
             Test
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion square expanded={expanded === 'panel2'} onChange={handleChange('panel2')}>
        <AccordionSummary 
            aria-controls="panel2d-content" 
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            id="panel2d-header">
          <Typography>Collapsible Group Item #2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
                   Test
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your content class just add this:

```
  content: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    margin: "auto",
    "&$expanded": {
     flexGrow: 0,
     margin: "auto",
    },
    "&:last-child": {
     marginLeft: "auto"
    }
   },
```

Adding the margin auto and specifying that the last child should have margin-left auto will allow you to keep the text centered while having the arrow in the right side of the accordion. Check this forked sandbox if you have questions: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-driscoll-xvzd5?file=/src/App.js:922-1097

Answer (score 1):

Jean182's answer worked for me, but it overrides automatic bottom and top margins for the header text, which I wanted to keep in. Here is my css, along with the necessary imports and withStyles call for anyone who might benefit from seeing it explicitly:

```
import { AccordionSummary } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const StyledAccordionSummary = withStyles({
  content: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    margin: "auto",
    marginTop: 12,
    marginBottom: 12,
    "&$expanded": {
     flexGrow: 0,
     margin: "auto",
    },
    "&:last-child": {
     marginRight: "auto"
    }
  },
})(AccordionSummary);
```

and then use the StyledAccordionSummary component where you would use the AccordionSummary one.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove flexGrow attribute like this :

```
const AccordionSummary = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)",
    // borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)',
    marginBottom: -1,
    minHeight: 56,
    "&$expanded": {
      minHeight: 56
    }
  },
  content: {
  
    "&$expanded": {
     
      margin: "12px 0"
    }
  },
  expanded: {},
  expandIcon: {
    order: 0
  }
})(MuiAccordionSummary);
```

here the [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shadow-ffi9q)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply keep the values of flexGrow as 1 for both, would have same effect.